# Have a refresh timer show a text when reaching 0 instead of continuing negative countdown

Tags: javascript

With the following code, the timer countdown in negative -1, -2, -3, -4 etc. while fetching the new data / reloading the site.

Is it possible when it reaches 0 to have it show the string "Refreshing site.." instead of the negative countdown?

```
(function countdown(remaining) {
    if(remaining <= 0)
        location.reload(true);
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = remaining;
    setTimeout(function(){ countdown(remaining - 1); }, 1000);
})(5); // 5 seconds
```

Comment: This will reload the page when the countdown hits zero, right?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Use a condition and use `clearTimeout()` to stop the timer

Comment: I think the intention here is to show a text for the time between the timer hitting 0 and the reload actually happening

Comment: What is the use-case for this?

Comment: Hey dear @JavaScript ! React here !!! Cool choice of profile name Mate :) CHEERS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an extra line of code to the if statement you already have to change the `innerHTML` of the countdown div to "Refreshing Site...".

Then add an else statement so that when remaining is greater than 0 the countdown `innerHTML` will be set to the time remaining and the `setTimeout` function will be set to run.

Because `setTimeout` is contained in the else, that line won't run once the timer hits 0 so the countdown function won't get called again.

```js
(function countdown(remaining) {
        if(remaining <= 0)
        {
            location.reload(true);
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Refreshing Site...";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = remaining;
            setTimeout(function(){ countdown(remaining - 1); }, 1000);
        }
    })(5); // 5 seconds
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you are actually starting your timer when `remaining` variable becomes less than 0. Because of your condition  `if(remaining <= 0)`. With your current code, I don't think you will be getting any positive value at all at the first place itself :)

I think you need to use `setTimer` outside of `if` condition and once your `remaining variable <=0` stop timer and perform additional logic of yours.

```
(function countdown(remaining) {
    const timer = setTimeout(function(){ countdown(remaining - 1); }, 1000);
    if(remaining <= 0)
    location.reload(true);
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = remaining;
    clearTimeout(timer);
})(5); // 5 seconds
```